# How to update users total points in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, points

I have a website where users submit posts that can be upvoted or downvoted.

At the moment a user's total earned points from all of his posts is not saved.

What is the best/common way to do this? How does a site like Reddit or StackOverflow do it?

Should I be adding and subtracting from the total user points every time someone votes on a post.

Comment: There are many ways you could go about this and all of them can be argued correct.  How do you want it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cache the result of the sum of votes per user over all posts, and invalidate the cache for each user when the user earns a new vote, or you could store the total count in the database and make sure that any upvote or downvote runs as a transaction that also updates the total.

Whether you do this using cache, or in MySQL using an extra table (I don't suggest putting it in your `users` table) depends on how big your site is and what you want to do with the votes.

Answer (score 0):

you should update this every time.. use ajax for better user experience.. here's a basic tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways One is stated by Habeeb
But what if you want to store everyone information who upvoted like stackoverflow then make two table one to store id of the post and other to store the user who upvoted the post
I mean Your Two table should be

```
POST                                      Upvote
Id     POST                              Id      User_id
```

1. Now when somebody upvote then just add a new record to table Upvote
   referncing the id of table POST.
2. When retrieving data you will need
   Left Join Method of sql